# Can you create a complex CSV file inside the Testdrive?

Tags: powershell, pester

I just want to ask if is it possible to create a complex csv file inside a Testdrive in creating a Pester test for a function? Complex in a sense that it has 13 headers and no null values?

Comment: Have you considered trying? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create any kind of file inside testdrive:\ (which are just like any kind of PSDrive) although it is of course only available temporarily within the context or describe block that it is used.

> TestDrive is a PowerShell PSDrive for file activity limited to the
>   scope of a single Describe or Context block.

https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/TestDrive